# How to merge two branches in git

Tags: git

I have a branch with name **development**. I made 4 commits and I needed to revert back to the first commit but while preserving these 4 commits. So I checked out the first commit as new branch **development_back**. Now I would like to merge these two branches, I do not want to continue in **development_back** branch but in **development** branch. Is it doable somehow?

Comment: Sure. What's the problem?

Comment: Now when I am in development branch and I try to choose development_back->merge - it makes a merge, but however I would like to overwrite it ..

Comment: to overwrite what exactly?

Answer (score 1):

IF I understand you correctly you currently have this:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
^                   ^
development_back    development
```

But want to get this:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
                    ^ development
                    ^ development_back
```

If it is correct then all you need is to merge `development` into `development_back`, not in the opposite way.  So checkout `development_back` branch and do `git merge --ff-only development`.  `--ff-only` flag ensures that you the merge will be fast-forward.

Comment: fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.

Comment: @Ladiko Are you sure you were on `development_back` branch when you tried to do the merge?